Selenium Firefox Download Not Working with Existing Session
I'm working on a Python Selenium automation script where I need to download a CSV file automatically from a webpage. I was trying to connect to an existing Firefox session using subprocess.Popen() and webdriver.Firefox with --connect-existing. The code works for logging in and navigating the page, but the file is not downloading automatically as expected. Below is a simplified version of my code:
import os
import glob
import time
import subprocess
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile

download_folder = "C:\\testing\\files"

firefox_options = Options()
firefox_profile = FirefoxProfile()
firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", download_folder)
firefox_profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "text/csv, application/csv")
firefox_options.profile = firefox_profile

command = ['C://Program Files (x86)//Mozilla Firefox//firefox.exe', '-marionette']
process = subprocess.Popen(command)
time.sleep(40)

service = Service(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install(), service_args=['--marionette-port', '2828', '--connect-existing'])
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefox_options, service=service)

time.sleep(3)
# Log in steps...
driver.find_element(By.ID, "userid").send_keys('username')
driver.find_element(By.ID, "password").send_keys('password')
driver.find_element(By.ID, "password").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# Wait for OTP and enter
time.sleep(10)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='otp_field']").send_keys('otp')
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id='otp_field']").send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(35)
# Navigate to export button
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='export_button']"))).click()
time.sleep(6)

# Check download folder for latest file
list_of_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(download_folder, '*'))
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
print("Latest downloaded file: ", latest_file)

The Problem:
The script works for navigating and interacting with the page, but the file does not download to the specified folder. I suspect it might be because I'm connecting to an existing Firefox session instead of opening a new one.
What I've Tried:

I have set the download preferences correctly using FirefoxProfile().
I am able to interact with the browser, log in, and click the export button.
I've verified that when manually running through the steps, the file downloads correctly.

Questions:

Could connecting to an existing Firefox session be the reason for this issue?
Should I avoid connecting to an existing session for setting download preferences?
Is there a way to properly connect to an existing session while ensuring download preferences work?

Any guidance on this issue would be appreciated.
